# Can I override ToolStripSystemRenderer to change the color of a dropdown backgroud, without changing the toolstrip background color?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a class that inherits ToolStripSystemRenderer and have added overriden various events to style my toolstrip the way I want. But I can't seem to change background of a button's dropdown menu, without changing the background color of the toolstrip itself.

Here's an example of the menu. I want to change that system color.

[image]

My renderer class is pretty simple at the moment.

```
public class AvertToolStripRenderer : ToolStripSystemRenderer
{
    protected override void OnRenderToolStripBorder(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        //base.OnRenderToolStripBorder(e);
    }
    protected override void OnRenderItemText(ToolStripItemTextRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        e.TextColor = Color.Black;
        base.OnRenderItemText(e);
    }
    protected override void OnRenderArrow(ToolStripArrowRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ArrowColor = Color.White;
        base.OnRenderArrow(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the renderer of your toolstrip(just in case you forgot about this detail):

```
YourToolstrip.Renderer = new AvertToolStripRenderer();
```

Next on your custom renderer class:

```
public class AvertToolStripRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    //rest of your implementation...

    protected override void OnRenderToolStripBackground(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripDropDown dr = e.ToolStrip as ToolStripDropDown;

        if (dr != null)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Beige, e.AffectedBounds);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah. I didn't realize I had to cast the ToolStrip to a ToolStripDropDown. I'm guessing all of the child controls inherit from ToolStrip? This worked perfectly. Thanks!